# How to prove a trigonometric identity $\tan(A)=\frac{\sin2A}{1+\cos 2A}$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that
$$
\tan(A)=\frac{\sin2A}{1+\cos 2A}
$$

I've tried a few methods, and it stumped my teacher.

Comment: Failure to prove is not surprising. It is quite false. For example, take $A=\pi/4$ ($45$ degrees).

Comment: I think you want $\cos(2A)$ there...

Comment: This is not a valid identity: try $A=\pi/4$ for example.

Answer (score 56):

Proof without words: $\tan(A)=\dfrac{\color{red}{\sin(2A)}}{\color{blue}{1}+\color{green}{\cos(2A)}}$

$\hspace{4cm}$[image: Proof]

Comment: I've never seen anyone prove a trig identity like that, but they should!

Answer (score 12):

The given equality is false. Set $A = \pi/2$. (Note: this applied to an earlier version of the problem).

Perhaps what you meant was

$$ \tan \frac{A}{2} = \frac{\sin A}{1 + \cos A}$$

or

$$ \tan A = \frac{\sin 2A}{1 + \cos 2A}$$

which is true, by using the half/double angle formulas.

$$\frac{\sin A}{1 + \cos A} = \frac{ 2 \sin A/2 \cos A/2}{2 \cos^2 A/2} = \tan A/2$$

Comment: This is one of my favorite identities. It is the basis for one form of $\operatorname{atan2}(x,y)=2\operatorname{atan}\left(\dfrac{y}{r+x}\right)$ which is useful if you have to compute $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ anyway. It also plays a significant role in the stereographic projection. (+1)

Comment: Nice proof, too :-)

Answer (score 5):

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{\sin(2A)}{1+\cos(2A)}=\tan(A)$$
Let's do LHS-RHS to prove it. I will try to make the left side equal the right side.
$$\frac{\sin(2A)}{1+\cos(2A)}$$
Using double angle identites for both sine and cosine:
$$\frac{2\sin(A)\cos(A)}{1+2\cos^2(A)-1}$$
How nice. The $1$ and $-1$ in the denominator cancel out.
$$\frac{2\sin(A)\cos(A)}{2\cos^2(A)}$$
Cancelling out the $\cos(A)$ in the numerator and the denominator yields:
$$\frac{2\sin(A)}{2\cos(A)}$$
We can also cancel out the $2$ in the numerator and the denominator.
$$\frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)}$$
$$=\tan(A)$$
$$\text{LHS=RHS}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore \dfrac{\sin(2A)}{1+\cos(2A)}=\tan(A)}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin 2A = 2 \sin A \cos A$$

$$\cos 2A = 2 \cos^2A - 1$$

Substitute these identities and you will get $\tan A$.

Comment: [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/120709/19341)?

Comment: I am downvoting this answer. BTW, you may want to look at the TeX edit I have made by clicking on the time stamp above my name.

Answer (score 2):

First, lets develop a couple of identities.
Given that $\sin 2A = 2\sin A\cos A$, and $\cos 2A = \cos^2A - \sin^2 A$ we have

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\tan 2A &=& \frac{\sin 2A}{\cos 2A}\\
&=&\frac{2\sin A\cos A}{\cos^2 A-\sin^2A}\\
&=&\frac{2\sin A\cos A}{\cos^2 A-\sin^2A}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 A}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2 A}}\\
&=&\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}
\end{array}$$
Similarly, we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\sec 2A &=& \frac{1}{\cos 2A}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\cos^2 A-\sin^2A}\\
&=&\frac{1}{\cos^2 A-\sin^2A}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 A}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2 A}}\\
&=&\frac{\sec^2 A}{1-\tan^2A}
\end{array}$$

But sometimes it is just as easy to represent these identities as

> $$\begin{array}{lll}
> (1-\tan^2 A)\sec 2A &=& \sec^2 A\\
> (1-\tan^2 A)\tan 2A &=& 2\tan A
> \end{array}$$

Applying these identities to the problem at hand we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\sin 2A}{1+\cos 2A}&=& \frac{\sin 2A}{1+\cos 2A}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\cos 2A}}{\frac{1}{\cos 2A}}\\
&=& \frac{\tan 2A}{\sec 2A +1}\\
&=& \frac{(1-\tan^2 A)\tan 2A}{(1-\tan^2 A)(\sec 2A +1)}\\
&=& \frac{(1-\tan^2 A)\tan 2A}{(1-\tan^2 A)\sec 2A +(1-\tan^2 A)}\\
&=& \frac{2\tan A}{\sec^2 A +(1-\tan^2 A)}\\
&=& \frac{2\tan A}{(\tan^2 A+1) +(1-\tan^2 A)}\\
&=& \frac{2\tan A}{2}\\
&=& \tan A\\
\end{array}$$
Lessons learned: As just a quick scan of some of the other answers will indicate, a clever substitution can shorten your workload considerably.