# How to justify the cosine sum rule geometrically in quadrants II, III, and IV?

Tags: trigonometry

The following diagram justifies the cosine angle sum rule quite nicely when $0 \alpha, \beta, \alpha + \beta < \pi / 2$.

[image: cosine sum rule]

**Question:** When extending this diagram to the other quadrants (i.e., when $\alpha + \beta > \pi/2$), the argument doesn't seem work anymore, at least not naturally? Am I mistaken? Does there exist a **geometric** argument for the cosine angle-sum rule for the other quadrants?

Comment: What’s your **geometric** definition of cosine for the other quadrants?

Comment: I suppose "adjacent over hypotenuse", or the usual unit circle definition.

Comment: Woo-hoo! [That's my diagram!](http://trigonography.com/2015/09/28/angle-sum-and-difference-for-sine-and-cosine/) :)  (Nice to know it's appreciated.) Adapting it to other quadrants isn't too much of an ordeal. [In this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382809/409), I show a couple of obtuse cases that give a sense of how things work.

Comment: This rule is the real part of  the complex exponential rule $e^{j(\alpha+\beta)} = e^{j\alpha}.e^{j\beta}$, which represents the product of complex numbers of length 1 also being a complex number of length 1. That is a good geometric representation.

Comment: By the way: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409), which discusses the development of trig values for angles beyond the first quadrant, may be helpful.