# Geometric proof for trigonometric angle sum formulas.

Tags: trigonometry

For some reason I'm starting to get nit picky about everything I have learned. In Geometry/ Algebra I learned how to prove the angle sum formulas, which follow from this picture (and a slightly different picture with $a$ and $b$ instead of $\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta$ :

[image]

But now that I realize it this argument only works if the angle sum $x$ follows the inequality $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. And every angle is larger than $0$, in radians.

How can we geometrically prove (to a high school student taking algebra/geometry)  the trigonometric sum formulas but for all angles?

**Definition**

Here is what I'll take to be the definition of sine and cosine (if you know of another definition I'd appreciate it if you share):

Let $(x,y)$ be a point in the Cartesian plane, let $\theta$ be the counterclockwise angle in radians from the positive $x$ axis to the segment connecting $(x,y)$ to the origin. Let a clockwise angle of $\theta$ be equivalent to  a counterclockwise  angle of $-\theta$, and vice versa. Take "sin" and "cos" to be $2\pi$ periodic functions. Let $r$ be the distance from $(x,y)$ to the origin. In other words $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then define:

$$\sin (\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$$

$$\cos (\theta)=\frac{x}{r}$$

Comment: This is very simple to do, if you are willing to accept identities like $sin(90-x)=sin(90+x)$ and such. If you aren't, the proof for this is very straightforward after drawing the unit circle.

Comment: I prefer to start straight from the definitions like sin= opp/hpp or more precisely $\sin (\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$. At least the second is what I think the definition of $\sin (\theta)$ is. @AnonymousPi

Comment: You have to go beyond that definition because if you write $\sin \theta=y/r$ you are saying that $\sin \theta >0$ and then you can't prove anything for an angle $\pi <\theta <2\pi$

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla As Arnaldo says it, you can't prove anything if you restrict yourself to that, because by definition the function for this values will be defined.

Comment: I have added my definitions please let me know if anything is unnecessary to be defined, and if I need to add anything @AnonymousPi

Comment: [This answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382809/409) ---and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409), on which it is based--- may be helpful.

Comment: Not to go off on too much of a tangent, but I've seen some authors (Rudin, I believe) define $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ functions as the real and complex part, respectively, of $e^{ix}$ (or the series representation of such). I am not aware how much that helps here, but I would be interested to know how many trig identities could be shown by this route.

Comment: @ThomasRasberry Basically all of them can. Of course, once you prove the geometric connection.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Using your definitions, it shouldn't be hard to prove the identities relating the sines or cosines of values between 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to general values. If I'm not wrong, it should be nothing more than triangle congruence.