# Trouble visualising geometrical proof of $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

We were taught a geometrical proof of the identity $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$ which consisted of drawing a triangle in a rectangle and looked like this:-

[image]

While I have no problem understanding this proof as long as the sum of the angles is an acute angle, I am not able to visualize how this proof works if the sum of the angles is not an acute angle.
How would this proof work if one angle is $120^\circ$ while the other is $285^\circ$ or $195^\circ$?

Comment: Woo-hoo! That's [my diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342/409) ... slightly tweaked and weirdly re-tinted by plagiarists, but mine nonetheless! :) ... Anyway, [here's a follow-up answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382809/409) that discusses adapting the figure to a couple of obtuse cases. If it sufficiently addresses your needs, then perhaps this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Blue I think this may come from https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408n/CurrentWeb/LM0-5-5.php. You could ask where they got it. There's also https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SinCosFormula2.shtml, without the colors, citing a book from 2000.

Comment: @Blue One of the figures at https://trigonometric-formulas.blogspot.com/2016/11/angle-sum-and-difference-identities.html looks even more like yours, including the enlarged $1$ and the color scheme.

Comment: @DavidK: I believe the Cut-the-Knot images (via Nelson's *Proofs without Words, II*) arise from "parallel evolution"; there are common variants of those, too, including ones embedded in the Unit Circle. Distinctive aspects of my figure that I like (and have been advocating since well before 2000) are reduced visual clutter by eliminating overlapping elements, and color-matching the similar sub-triangles. Of course, I don't claim to be the first person *in history* to concoct "my" figure ... but it seems pretty clear that my *particular rendition* has (in)directly "inspired" others. Yay, me! :)

Comment: I came up with what I believe is an all-angles proof in a single diagram, although not quite as pretty and obvious as the one in the question. That diagram is also an answer to the much earlier (and more general) question, [How can I understand and prove the "sum and difference formulas" in trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1292/139123) Because an answer should be posted only once, I've posted my answer under the older question. [Here it is, if you're interested.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4521260/139123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See picture below. Note that angle $\beta$ is in fourth quadrant, that's why $BC=-\sin\beta$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! this really helps! BTW, what did you use to make this image?

Comment: I've used GeoGebra