# Simple trigonometry: negative cos and sin

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have some problem with awareness of school material. How can we say that $\cos\phi$ or $\sin\phi$ would be negative? The metric - a function that takes only positive values in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that in school about that sayng that $\phi$ -- obtuse angle. But for now it is looking little bit strange.

Comment: You might find [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) helpful.

Comment: You should explain in your question, as you have in comments below gimusi's answer, that your interest is the trigonometric form of complex numbers. (Changing the `real-analysis` tag to `complex-numbers` would also be appropriate). Perhaps also explain how your confusion about metrics is involved. As it is, the quesiton is a bit vague.

Comment: @Blue So my confusion in that metric $\rho(x,y)$ -- the function in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, and in school $\cos$ and $\sin$ define as relation between segments of a certain length. The norm -- length -- always positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand that we need to recall that **by definition** $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are precisely the coordinates of the point $P(x,y)$ on the unitary circle such that ray OP forms an angle $\theta$ with positive $x$ axis (usually assuming as positive the counterclockwise direction).

Since the equation for the unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$, $\cos A$ and $\sin A$ can also assume negative values, for exampleat an angle $180°$ corresponds the point $(-1,0)$ and therefore

- $\cos (180°)=-1$
- $\sin (180°)=0$

[image]

Comment: Ye, I am thinking about that trig notation of $c\in\mathbb{C}$ can using the negative $\cos$ and $\sin$. But my intuition of metrics is broken

Comment: @Arsenii Are you referring to $$\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta} }2$$

Comment: I dont know what is this :D 
I am about $z = a+bi = |z|(\frac{a}{|z|} + \frac{b}{|z|} i)$, where $a$ and $b$ can be negative real number

Comment: @Arsenii That's exactly the trigonometric (polar) representation of complex numbers via trigonometric functions. According to the given definition $a/|z| = \cos \theta$ and $y/|z| = \sin \theta$.

Comment: @Arsenii Refer also to [Polar & Exponential Form](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx)

Comment: Okey, thx, I am going to read it too

Comment: @Arsenii You are welcome! Bye