# Prove the rules to find trig. functions of angles greater than $90^{\circ}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can anybody proof

"the rules used to find trigonometric functions of angles greater than $90^{\circ}$"

i.e. if angle$= ( nπ ± θ)$, then its trigonometric function $=$ trigonometric function of $θ$ and sign is decided by ASTC (CAST) rule ?

Comment: the rules follow from angle addition formulas

Comment: Can you just use the sum and difference formulas cos(x+y) = cos x cos y - sin x sin y, etc.?

Comment: with $y=\pi$, e.g.

Comment: See, for instance, [this ancient answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be in the first quadrant, so sin$(\theta)$ and cos$(\theta)$ are positive.

Then tan($\theta)=\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$ is positive too.

Now $\theta+\dfrac\pi2$ is in the second quadrant.  Using the [trigonometric addition formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html),

$\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\sin(\theta)\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)+\cos(\theta)\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)=\cos(\theta) $ is positive,

$\cos(\theta+\dfrac\pi2)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\dfrac\pi2)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\dfrac\pi2)=-\sin(\theta)$ is negative,

and therefore tan$\left(\theta+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac\pi2\right)}{\cos\left(\theta+\dfrac\pi2\right)}$ is negative in the second quadrant.

Similar arguments work for $\theta+\pi$ in the third quadrant:

$\sin(\theta+\pi)=-\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta+\pi)=-\cos(\theta)$   are negative, so their ratio $\tan(\theta+\pi)$ is positive.

I'm leaving the fourth quadrant $\left(\theta+\dfrac{3\pi}2\right)$ as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

From a logical standpoint (not proof as such), I understood it this way:

1st quadrant unit circle,
x is positive, y is positive and hence all trigonometric functions are positive

2nd quadrant unit circle,
x is negative, y is positive 
sin = y / 1 = y 
cos = - x / 1 = -x 
tan, because one of the sin and cos is negative tan will be negative

3rd quadrant unit circle,
x is negative, y is negative
sin = -y / 1 = - y
cos = -x / 1 = -x
since tan is a division of sin and cos, negative cancels out and is positive.

4th quadrant unit circle,
x is positive, y is negative
sin = -y / 1 = -y
cos = x / 1 = x
since one of the sin and cos is negative, tan is negative