# How is $\sin 90° = 1$ possible?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, triangles, ratio

How can two angles of a triangle be equal to $90°$? If two angles were $90°$, this would mean that the [two sides would be parallel and the angle of the third side would be equal to 0](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-angle-between-parallel-lines). Thus, there would be only two vertices and this wouldn't be a triangle at all, ultimately making $\sin 90° = 1$ impossible.

Comment: There's more to the sine function than triangles.

Comment: See here the definition of the $\sin$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

Comment: Trigonometric functions can be defined beyond triangles by invoking rotation along the unit circle, and even more, independently of geometry. For instance, one can define sine function by $$\sin(x^{\circ}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \left(\frac{\pi}{180}x\right)^{2n+1} $$ for any *complex number* $x$.

Comment: I applaud this very good first question from a new user

Comment: If you want to stick to triangles, you may think of $\sin(90)$ as the degenerate case for a triangle. Like, $\sin(85) = 0.996$, $\sin(86) = 0.997, \sin(89) = 0.9998\ldots$. So it seems $\sin(90) = 1$

Comment: @rsadhvika Well, I think this fact is known by the OP. He's just trying to figure out shouldn't $\sin (90^o)$ be undefined if there is no triangle at all?

Comment: Isn't it more natural to ask "how is $\sin 0° = 0$ possible?" Good question, by the way.

Comment: I like to think that [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) to the question ["When the trig functions moved from the right triangle to the unit circle?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145616/409) could be helpful to you.

Comment: With regards to the first comment, we need the unit circle definition to compute sines of angles greater than $90º$ and negative angles. Otherwise, there would be no way to prove basic theorems such as $\sin(-\theta) = - \sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider polar coordinates, $(r \cos\theta, r \sin \theta)$ in a unit circle such that $r=1$. Then, we can see that, the mapping in the first quadrant inside the unit circle is just $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. Now, consider a moving point $A$ starting from $\theta=0°$ to $\theta=90°$ on the circumference of the circle. Now, $OA$ is the hypotenuse of the right angle triangle inside the circle. Now, it is clear that at $\theta=90°$, the hypotenuse and the perpendicular are the same line in the $x$-axis (i.e., they coincide). So, $\sin(90°)=\frac{p}{h}=1$. 
As per your argument, the case is two sides coinciding rather than being parallel, because by Pythagoras theorem, we have $h^2=p^2+b^2$, so if $p$ increases then $b$ must decrease, and $h=p$ iff $b=0$.

Where, h  is the radius of the unit circle, p is the perpendicular drawn from (aka height) the point in the circumference to the x-axis, and b is the distance of intersection of p and x-axis from the origin.

Comment: I made some edits, but we still need to know what $h,p,b$ are

Comment: Thank you. $h$ is the radius of the unit circle, $p$ is the perpendicular drawn from (aka height) the point in the circumference to the x-axis, and $b$ is the distance of intersection of $p$ and x-axis from the origin.

Comment: @problem_cracker It would be good if mentioned what $h,p,b$ are in the answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can very well admit the concept of flat triangles (coming in two flavors, with a $0°$ and a $180°$ angle).

Anyway, the usual definition of the sine *does not involve a triangle*. Rather, the trigonometrical circle and the projection of a point at a given angle to the vertical axis. Indisputably, $\sin90°=1$. Simlarly, $\cos90°=0$.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial Pythagorean triple, generated by Euclid's formula where $m=n$ such as $(A,B,C)=(0,2,2)$, is a vertical line $(A=0)$ on the $y$ axis. Since $\frac{C}{B}=1, \sin90^\circ=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, this [answer to a previous similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145616/when-the-trig-functions-moved-from-the-right-triangle-to-the-unit-circle/145828#145828) may well help.

To answer your question directly: I offer that mathematicians made $\sin(x)$ “well defined” for values of $x$ that are smaller than $0^{\circ}$ or larger than $90^{\circ}$ (that is, outside the range of values that are valid for an interior angle of a triangle) when it became useful to do so. [“Well defined”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined) is a technical term that means, roughly, that everyone agrees on the answer.

As a simple example, imagine an object that is moving in the plane at constant velocity. The velocity can be described as a speed $v$ and an angle $\theta$ measured clockwise from the $x$ axis. Now suppose that we ask the question, “How fast is the object moving in the $y$ direction?”

If $\theta$ is less than $90^{\circ}$ then trigonometry gives the answer $v \sin(\theta)$. For values of $\theta$ equal or larger than $90^{\circ}$, it’s possible to calculate an answer by deducting an appropriate multiple of $90^{\circ}$ to bring $\theta$ back into the range of valid triangle interior angles. But that’s tedious.
The answer “should” be $v \sin(\theta)$ for any direction $\theta$. To make this answer work, the definition of $\sin$ has to be extended from the range of valid triangle interior angles $(0^{\circ},90^{\circ})$ to the range of valid directions $[0^{\circ},360^{\circ})$. In this extension definition, $\sin(90^{\circ})=1$.