# Proof of Angles going beyond 90 deg in Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, intuitionistic-logic

Since we’re introduced to trigonometric ratios in terms of opposite, perpendicular and hypotenuse, all of which are a part of a right angled triangle. This defines the ratios for angles greater than 0 and less than 90.

For angles greater than 90, we drop a perpendicular from the end-point of the moving arm of the angle and we take the acute angle made by the end-point, the pivot point and the point on the x axis where the perpendicular is dropped.

My question being; The way we calculate angles greater than 90, is it defined or derived? If it is defined, then what is the intuition behind defining it like that and if it is derived , proof (and how it’s connected to 0 to 90 part).

I do realise that these ratios were never really meant to be specific to the triangle.But then again, they were introduced that way.

Also can you please recommend some books which explain trigonometry in great detail?

Thank you!

Comment: Or is this just Maths. As in we make a theory, and add stuff to it so long as it does'nt contradict with the original theory just to increase its effectiveness or range?  (Please help me understand that is math Absolute or is it more of if it works it is to be that ?

Comment: Please don’t repost your unanswered questions, especially with absolutely no changes and only after [the original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3646525/265466). That’s not the accepted way to do things here.

Comment: Im sorry i thought my original question would be closed so thats why i reposted it

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of defining the sine function depending on what you want to use it on. So if all you need is acute angles, then the right angled triangle works just fine. But what if you see a physics equation that plugs time into a sine function (such as those seen in harmonic motion) and so this is not always going to be an acute angle, so we need a broader definition. This is where the idea of the unit circle is often employed.
[image: Trigonometric ratios from the unit circle]

This allows you to define, for any real angle $\theta$, what the value of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ (and from that all the other trig ratios you might like) is. This works for angles other than acute angles because you can just keep going round and round the circle and the coordinates of the point are always $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.
This can be seen as taking an approach with agrees with what we have already in the acute angles case and then adding to it so that it works in new contexts too.
So someone who thought trigonometry was only about right angled triangles might make the argument here that this is no longer trigonometry - we've just made something up and there's no evidence that this is what it is actually like.
But this is kind of the point, we have to make stuff up in maths. As long as it's consitent with what we had before i.e. it doesn't break stuff, then it's fine. And if it turns out to be useful (as this very much is) then it's far better than fine.

A very similar idea applies when you try to extend the sine function defintion to apply to even more than the real numbers. It can be shown using calculus that the sine function is equal to an infinite polynomial (this is how a lot of calculators actually work out arbitrary trig values). Now there's no reason that this infinite polynomial should only be allowed to have real numbers plugged into it, you can start plugging imaginary or complex numbers into it and the polynomial just deals with it and gives you an answer (you can even find the sine of a matrix using the series defintion). But this has no representation looking at our poor old triagnles we had in the beginning, what has happened?

We've just used the idea of abstraction away from the original circumstances it was envisioned within and generalised it so it becomes more useful and can answer more problems. It still works fine for acute angles, it just works for a whole lot more beyond that.

So to summarise, we can define stuff however we like and as long it doesn't mess with what we've already got then we can use it along-side everything else we've already got. And often this extension turns out to be useful so that we can solve problems we didn't have techniques to solve before. And if it's useful and works then often it becomes the accepted definition.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up!!!! Seriously, Thanks!!!