# Why are the values of $\sin (\theta)$ and $\csc(\theta)$ positive in the second quadrant?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the value of $\sin (\theta)$ and $\csc(\theta)$ positive in the second quadrant?
Similarly why the value of other trigonometric ratios so in other quadrants?

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) may (or may not) be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the sine is the projection of the point  on the trigonometric circle with curvilinear abscissa $\theta$. As to the cosecant, it is the reciprocal of the sine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all note that the cosecant is just $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$, so they are both positive or both negative.

In the second you can view the sin of $\theta$ as the value of the vertical segment that is perpendicular to the $X$ axis drawn from the point where the radios of angle $\theta$ cuts the unit circle, as the figure shows:

[image]

Thus, sine is positive in the first two quadrants, but negative in the last two.

Answer (score 1):

You may recall this image:

[image: Quadrants]

Now, the unit circle definition tells us that $\cos \theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point whose radius makes angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis.

Therefore, in the first quadrant ($0<\theta<90^\circ$), both $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are positive, and in the second quadrant ($90^\circ<\theta<180^\circ$), $\cos\theta$ is negative and $\sin\theta$ is positive, and so on for third and fourth quadrants.

Define:
$$\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\text{ and }\csc\theta=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$
Thus, the sign of $\sec\theta$ is the same as $\cos\theta$ and the sign of $\csc\theta$ is the same as $\sin\theta$.

Define:
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\text{ and }\cot\theta=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
Thus, the signs of $\tan\theta$ and $\cot\theta$ are positive, if $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ have same signs, and negative, if different.

For example, for the second quadrant, $\cos\theta$ is negative and $\sin\theta$ is positive. So, $\sec\theta$ is negative and $\csc\theta$ is positive, and , $\tan\theta$ and $\cot\theta$ are negative.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because cartesian coordinate system is defined in that way. This needs explanation, I know.

We have generalised trigonometry, from only inputs between $0$ and $90$ to any real number $\theta$, by using a [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) (Wikipedia link) on cartesian coordinate system with its centre on origin i.e. $(0,0)$.

To do this generalisation we define $\sin (\theta)$  as $y-axis$ of the the end of the point on radius of that [unit circle](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:trig/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:unit-circle/a/trig-unit-circle-review) (Khan Academy link).
Now it is by definition that in $2nd$ and $1st$ quadrant $y-coordinate$ is positive, so clearly it follows that $sine$ function must be positive in $2nd$ and $1st$quadrant as it is $y-axis$. Now since $\sin (\theta)$ is positive, so must be $\csc(\theta)$. As we have defined it as reciprocal of $\sin (\theta)$, now reciprocal  of any positive number must be a positive number($0$ is not positive).

Now we have similarly defined $\cos(\theta)$ as the $x-coordinate$ of the the end of the point on radius of that unit circle, similarly it must be positive in $1st$ and $4rth$ quadrant.
Following image may be helpful:
[image]

It is left as an exercise for you to find why other trigonometric functions ..... you understand what I mean(right)!

Comment: You mean $y$-coordinate for $\sin\theta$ and $x$-coordinate for $\cos\theta$.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig Yes?.... I dont understand what you mean by that statement. If you are asking for clarification that if the sinθ and cosθ are defined  as y -coordinate and x-coordinate respectively then the answer is Yes.

Comment: What I am saying is that you should replace $y$-axis by $y$-coordinate and $x$-axis by $x$-coordinate.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig Thanks.