# Why can sin, cos, and tan be negative?

Tags: trigonometry

In a Cartesian coordinate system, there are 4 Quadrans. Lets take Quadrant 4 for reference. X there is positive and Y is negative. I understand that the radius in a unit circle is 1. This makes the sin of a 330 degree angle -1/2. But from the definition of sin = opposite/hypothenuse, it should always be positive since the length of a triangle should always be positive. I haven't seen a length of -2cm. So why is it different here? Why can't we just say that the sin of a +330 degree angle is 1/2. Why should we make it negative.

Comment: Opposite of what over hypothenuse of what? So, what triangle has an angle of 330 degrees?

Comment: The definition via opposite/hypothenuse only works in the 1st quadrant, for other angles you have to tweak this definition.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145828/409) may (or may not) provide some insights.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Unit_circle_definition

Comment: Trigonometric functions are not *defined* via triangles; that identification came later, and it only works under suitable conditions; in particular, since you work on a right triangle with one angle of $90^{\circ}$, and the angles of a triangle add up to $180^{\circ}$, the correspondence can only work for angles $\alpha$ with $0\leq\alpha\leq 90^{\circ}$. To extend it to other angles, one uses the unit circle and the coordinates of the points on the circle, as this is related to the original connection of sines with half chords of the double angle.

Comment: You should change your memorized definition to *signed length of opposite*/hypotenuse, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Ugh; if you’re going to do that, surely it’s better to just change it to “the coordinates of the point on the unit circle, $(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))$.

Comment: I disagree with you, @Arturo. This is not the only place such notion show up. Very similar is the geometric interpretation of the dot product $x\cdot y = \|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$, where $\|y\|\cos\theta$ is the *signed length* of the projection of $y$ onto $x$. It's really the same issue. My pedagogical point stands, although perhaps not for a first-week trig student.

Comment: "I haven't seen a length of -2cm." I haven't seen a an angle of 330 in a triangle, so all is good.