# Trigonometric equality involving $a\sin \alpha + b \sin \beta$

Tags: trigonometry

I was watching [this video on orthogonal](https://youtu.be/TNiS4lgcIzg?t=2m37s) signals and the author used a trigonometric equality that I haven't seen before (at the bottom of the screenshot):

[image]

Could anyone tell me where I can find a proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the image, $\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\cos\theta$

Now $A\sin(wt+\psi)+B\sin(wt+\phi)=\sin wt(A\cos\psi+B\cos\phi)+\cos wt(A\sin\psi+B\sin\phi)$

Now can you derive $p\sin x+q\cos x =\sqrt{p^2+q^2}\sin\left(x+\arcsin\dfrac p{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right)$

Comment: How do you derive the last step?

Comment: @qed, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948329/how-is-a-sin-theta-b-cos-theta-c-sin-theta-phi-derived OR  http://www.math-only-math.com/a-cos-theta-plus-b-sin-theta-equals-c.html