# Geometric meaning of $a \sin \theta + b \cos\theta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Does anyone know of a geometric interpretation of $a \sin\theta + b \cos\theta$? I know that it can be derived by the angle sum identity, but is there a geometric significance of this identity?

Comment: It's a dot product.

Comment: $a \sin\theta + b \cos\theta$ is an expression, not an identity.

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: The identity I meant is actually this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948329/how-is-a-sin-theta-b-cos-theta-c-sin-theta-phi-derived. Forgot to write it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ and draw two parallel lines through opposite vertices at angle $\theta$ to one of the sides.

Then your ecpression is the perpendicular distance between these two lines (for suitable choice of $\theta$).

Comment: Oh this is very nice. The identity is immediate.