# Explaining why $c_1e^{-\beta t}\sin(⁡rt) + c_2e^{-\beta t}\cos⁡(⁡rt) = Ae^{-\beta t}\cos(rt+\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry

Could someone kindly explain to me why these two expressions are equal?

$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=c_1e^{-\beta t}\sin(⁡rt) + c_2e^{-\beta t}\cos⁡(⁡rt) \\[4pt]
&= Ae^{-\beta t}\cos(rt+\phi)
\end{align}$$

with $r := \sqrt{\omega_0^2-\beta^2 }$, where $c_1$, $c_2$ or $A$ and $\phi$ are the pair of arbitrary real constants, while $\beta$ and $\omega_0$ are the known quantities and $t$ represents the independent variable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'l get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: See, for instance, ["Why does $A\sin k(x+c)=a\sin kx+b\cos kx$ imply that $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan c=−b/a$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856580/why-does-a-sinkxc-a-sinkxb-coskx-imply-that-a-sqrta2b2-and/856600#856600).

Answer (score 0):

$x(t)$ is a linear combination (addition) of a $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions. Because a $\sin$ function can be expressed as a shifted $\cos$ function, we can express $x(t)$ as an addition of two $\cos$ functions (one is shifted, the other one is not shifted), which results in a (shifted) $\cos$ function. That's why $x(t) = a_1 \sin(bt) + a_2 \cos(bt)$ with $a_1 = c_1~e^{-βt}, a_2 = c_2~e^{-βt}$ and $b=⁡\sqrt{ω_0^2-β^2 }$ is the same as $x(t) = A~e^{-βt}~\cos\left(⁡b~t+ φ\right)$, if we choose/calibrate the right constants $A,c_1,c_2$ and $\varphi$ and we can express the amplitude $A$ and the shift angle $\varphi$ in terms of the amplitudes $c_1$ and $c_2$. Just set some values for $t$ like $t = 0$ and $t = \frac{\pi}{2b}$. Then we get $x(t=0)=c_2 =A\cos(\varphi) \Rightarrow c_2^2 = A^2\cos^2(\varphi)$ and $x(t=\frac{\pi}{2b})=c_1=A\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\varphi)=-A\sin(\varphi) \Rightarrow c_1^2 = A^2\sin^2(\varphi)$. Then add the two equations and use the identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ to get $A = \sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}$. Divide the equations to get $\tan(\varphi)=\large{\frac{c_1}{c_2}}.$

This equation is a solution for some mechanical problem: [Differential equation for describing the swing of a spring](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7f49/96f00119b5f5f7050bf167bf9842a914125f.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Mr Hossam for your clear answer.

Comment: It's not very clear, but you get the idea

Comment: I'm a new user and I still don't know how to use the forum well, but I'll try to explain my questions more clearly the next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}x(t) &= Ae^{-\beta t}\cos(rt+\phi) \\
\\
&=Ae^{-\beta t}\left[\cos(rt)\cos(\phi)-\sin(rt)\sin(\phi)\right]\\
\\
&=Ae^{-\beta t}\left[-\sin(\phi)\sin(rt)+\cos(\phi)\cos(rt)\right]\\
\\
&=-A\sin(\phi)e^{-\beta t}\sin(rt)+A\cos(\phi)e^{-\beta t}\cos(rt)\\
\\
&= c_1 e^{-\beta t}\sin(rt)+c_2e^{-\beta t}\cos(rt)\\
\end{align*}$$

If you need an explanation of the Ptolemy (cosine angle sum) formula used in the above derivation, this site provides one:
https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/trig/ptolemy.html