# Rewriting $\sin x - \cos x$ to help in simplifying $y=\log_2(\sin x-\cos x+3\sqrt{2})-\log_2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was required to solve the function for it domain and range, $$y=\log_2(\sin x-\cos x+3\sqrt{2})-\log_2\sqrt{2}$$

Here I'm not able to solve due my inability to manipulate $\sin x-\cos x$. Are there any important ones that I should try to remember?

Comment: Do you mean $\log(2(\cdots))$ (the natural log of two-times something) or $\log_2(\cdots)$ (the base-$2$ log of something)? Also, I don't see an inequality.

Comment: this isn't an inequity, this is a function.

Comment: $a\sin x+b\cos x+c=A\cos (x+\varphi)$ (added angle formula for example), into $\log_2 (\ldots)$.

Comment: This question is about the relation you probably need: ["Why does $A\sin k(x+c)=a\sin kx+b\cos kx$ imply that $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan c=−b/a$?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856580/409) (Take $k=1$, $a=1$, and $b=-1$.)

Comment: Where is that inequality ?

Comment: im sorry, i have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to introduce what we call normalizer factor that is defined as:
$$b=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the coefficent of sine and cosine function (in this case both $1$). So we multiply and divide by $\sqrt2$, obtaining:
$$sin(x)-\cos(x)=\sqrt2(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\sin(x)-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cos(x))$$
Now we can notice the expansion of $\sin(x+\pi/4)$, so all becomes:
$$\sqrt2\sin(x-\pi/4)$$

Comment: @MrKhonsu: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to solve

$$\sin x-\cos x=a.$$

You can address this by squaring, while you recall that the LHS must have the sign of $a$:

$$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=1-\sin 2x=a^2$$

so that

$$\sin 2x=1-a^2.$$