# How to write $x \sin A + y \sin B$ as single trigonometric funtion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I came upon this while doing waves:

How do you write $x \sin A+y \sin B$ in the form of $z\sin(\cdots)$?

I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed.

Edit: It was  $z\sin(C)$ . My mistake.
Maybe there is a mistake in my assumption that it can be expressed in that way. So I'll give the reason behind it

Waves can be expressed as $$y_{1}=A_{1}\sin(kx+\omega t+\delta_{1})$$ and $$y_{2}=A_{2}\sin(kx+\omega t+\delta_{2})$$

Let net be $y$

Therefore, $$y=y_{1}+y_{2}$$

Clearly,
 $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = -k\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

So, y can be expressed as a linear combination of x and t (leading to the conclusion that sum of two propogatory waves in the same direction fives another propogatory wave). Its probably a sine or cos function as we are adding up two sines. While we were doing superposition of waves, we assumed same amplitude for mathematical simplicity but I can vaguely remember my teacher telling me it was trivial for different amplitudes but I can't figure it out now.

Sorry if I've made a stupid mistake as I am still a beginner in waves.

Edit again: -k in partial differential equation.

Comment: None can be seen on Wolframalpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xSinA%2BySinB in terms of alternate representations

Comment: If $x=y=1$ there seems to be a hope as there is a formula for sina+sinb

Comment: If $x^2+y^2\ne 1$ you will need complex numbers for this.

Comment: @user254665 : What you have in mind is not at all clear to me. If you have $x\sin A + y\sin B$, you can write that as $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\left( \frac x {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \sin A + \frac y {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \sin B \right) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}(u\sin A + v\sin B),$$ and then $u^2+v^2=1$. Then you could say something like $u=\cos\alpha$ and $v=\sin\alpha$. But where do you go from there?  If you'd had $\sin A$ and $\cos A$ instead of $\sin A$ and $\sin B$, it would be easy, but it said $\sin A$ and $\sin B$, where $A$ and $B$ are different variables.Why would the fact that $x^2+y^2\ne1$ matter? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. The Q was to write  $x\sin A+y\sin B=\sin C$, not $z\sin C.$ If $0\ne x^2+y^2\ne 1$  this can be done but not with real $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer the question you *wanted* to ask (as indicated in the edited question) rather than the question as originally written,
whose answer you presumably already knew.

The question is, 
if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the following functions of $x$ and $t$,
\begin{align}
y_1 &= A_1 \sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_1) \\
y_2 &= A_2 \sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_2),
\end{align}
how do we find a definition of $y_1+y_2$ as a function of $x$ and $t$
in the form
$$
y_1 + y_2 = A_3 \sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_3)?
$$

---

To keep the formulas a little more manageable, let $u = kx + \omega t$.
Using the angle-sum formula for sine,
\begin{align}
\sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_1)
 &= \sin\delta_1 \cos u + \cos\delta_1 \sin u, \\
\sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_2)
 &= \sin\delta_2 \cos u + \cos\delta_2 \sin u.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
y_1 + y_2 &= A_1(\sin\delta_1 \cos u + \cos\delta_1 \sin u)
            + A_2(\sin\delta_2 \cos u + \cos\delta_2 \sin u) \\
&= (A_1\sin\delta_1 + A_2\sin\delta_2)\cos u
   + (A_1\cos\delta_1 + A_2\cos\delta_2)\sin u.
\end{align}
So if $A = A_1\sin\delta_1 + A_2\sin\delta_2$
and $B = A_1\cos\delta_1 + A_2\cos\delta_2$,
we're looking for $A_3$ and $\delta_3$ that will generally satisfy
$$
A_3 \sin(u + \delta_3) = A \cos u + B \sin u.
$$
Working [from this answer to a related question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402561)
we want $A_3$ and $\delta_3$ such that $(A_3)^2 = A^2 + B^2$ and
$\tan\delta_3 = \frac AB$.
Recognizing that once we find a suitable $\delta_3$,
we can always add or subtract any whole multiple of $2\pi$
without changing the truth of any of our equations,
the solution is something of the form
\begin{gather}
A_3 = \pm\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}, \\
\delta_3 = \arctan \frac AB \quad\text{or}\quad
 \delta_3 = \pi + \arctan \frac AB.
\end{gather}
But since 
$A_3 \sin\left(u + \left(\pi + \arctan \frac AB\right)\right)
= -A_3 \sin\left(u + \left(\arctan \frac AB\right)\right)$,
we really have only two solutions to consider, and might as well
set $A_3$ to the positive square root of $A^2 + B^2$.
And then we merely need consider what happens when $u=0$,
that is, check whether $A_1 \sin(\delta_1) + A_2 \sin(\delta_2)$
is positive or negative, to decide whether $\sin(\delta_3)$
must be positive or negative and therefore whether to set
$\delta_3 = \arctan \frac AB$ or $\delta_3 = \pi + \arctan \frac AB$.

---

Alternatively, as one of my physics professors, Ken Lane, liked to say,
"let's complexify" the problem. We know that in general,
$$
e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta.
$$
If we take the real and imaginary parts of this function, we have two
sinusoidal functions $\frac\pi2$ radians out of phase.
As I recall, Prof. Lane liked to take the real part of this function as
the "wave", which is convenient if we want a phase-shifted cosine, but
you're looking for a phase-shifted sine, so it will be more convenient
to take the imaginary part.
The imaginary part of $e^{i\theta}$ is
$\newcommand{\Im}{\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}}
 \Im\left(e^{i\theta}\right) = \sin\theta$,
and
$$
\Im\left(A_k e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_k)}\right)
 = A_k \sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_k).
$$
So we can rewrite $y_1$ and $y_2$ as the imaginary parts of
\begin{align}
z_1 &= A_1 e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_1)}, \\
z_2 &= A_2 e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_2)}.
\end{align}
Adding the two functions together,
\begin{align}
z_1 + z_2 &= A_1 e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_1)}
            + A_2 e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_2)} \\
&= \left(A_1 e^{i\delta_1} + A_2 e^{i\delta_2}\right)
     e^{i(kx + \omega t)} \\
&= (A_1 \cos\delta_1 + A_2 \cos\delta_2 
         + i (A_1 \sin\delta_1 + A_2 \sin\delta_2))
     e^{i(kx + \omega t)}
\end{align}
Let $A = A_1 \sin\delta_1 + A_2 \sin\delta_2$ and
$B = A_1 \cos\delta_1 + A_2 \cos\delta_2$; then we need merely
write the complex number $B + iA$ in the form $A_3 e^{i\delta_3}$,
which we do by setting $A_3 = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$
and either $\delta_3 = \arctan\frac AB$ (if $A$ is positive)
or $\delta_3 = \pi + \arctan\frac AB$ (if $A$ is negative).
We then have
$$
z_1 + z_2 = \left( A_3 e^{i \delta_3} \right) e^{i(kx + \omega t)}
 = A_3 e^{i(kx + \omega t + \delta_3)}
$$
and
$$
y_1 + y_2 = \Im\left( z_1 + z_2 \right)
= A_3 \sin(kx + \omega t + \delta_3).
$$