# how to simplify $a\cos(bx)+c\sin(dx)$ into one cosine function

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to figure out how to simplify the above expression.

I'd imagine it is easy to simplify the sine term into a cosine term by adding a phase shift, but then how do you add the two cosine functions together into one cosine function.

Comment: If $b\neq d$ and neither $a$ nor $c$ is zero, I think you're out of luck. Take a look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D2+cos(3x)%2B3+sin(4x) for example; there is no way to fit that to a single cosine function.

Comment: I agree with David K.  These are nonlinear functions, so not sure what can be accomplished here if $b \neq d$ and $ac \neq 0$.  Especially if by simplifying you mean ending up with one term instead of two summands.

Comment: what if we have the condition that b=d?

Comment: If $b=d$ then you have a slightly simpler version of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694278/how-to-write-x-sin-a-y-sin-b-as-single-trigonometric-funtion/1694540#1694540 -- skip the first few paragraphs and start just before the equation $A_3 \sin(u + \delta_3) = A \cos u + B \sin u.$ On the right hand side of that equation, to translate it into your notation, $A=a$, $B=c$, and $u=bx=dx$. The left hand side of that equation will be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It had what I was looking for!