# Prove the Identity - Double Angle

Tags: trigonometry

$\cot(A) =\sin(2A)/(1-\cos(2A))$

I've tried converting the top and bottom by

every single one of their equivalent formulas but didn't have any luck.

Thank you

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get $ \cot(\theta/2)$ from $ \frac {\sin \theta} {1 - \cos \theta} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160982/how-to-get-cot-theta-2-from-frac-sin-theta-1-cos-theta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin {align}\frac {\sin(2A)}{1-\cos(2A)}&=\frac{2\sin A \cos A}{1-\cos^2A+\sin^2A}\\
&=\frac {2 \sin A \cos A}{2\sin^2A}\\ &=\cot A \end {align}$$

Comment: On your second step I thought that Cos(2A) was equivalent to cos^2A-sin^2A

Comment: @JeremyHernandez:  yes, that is what I used.  The $\cos(2A)$ has a minus sign in front.

Comment: Oh ok, so you moved the minus sign to the front of the identity. Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer leaves me wondering what "every single one of their equivalent formulas" meant in the original question. These are the first formulas one would try. The formulas used here seem to be the obvious ones to try first. Perhaps there was an error in dealing with the negative signs, but since the efforts weren't shown, we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: @DavidK I am sorry i left this out. Where I got stuck : 2sinAcosA/1-cos2A where cos2A is equal to cos^2-sin^2. So in the denominator i had 1 - cos^2-sin^2 and i wasnt sure how to convert that into an identity.

Comment: So it _was_ a sign error. I see now that the previous comments gave a clue about this. Now that we have seen that it should have been $1-\cos^2A+\sin^2A$ (because that's equal to $1 - (\cos^2A-\sin^2A)$), perhaps this will help you in future exercises.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You have the *linearisation formula*:
$$\sin^2A==\frac{1-\cos 2A}2.$$