# Prove $\frac{1+\cos{(2A)}}{\sin{(2A)}}=\cot{A}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am sorry to ask so many of these questions in such as short time span.

But how would I prove this following trigonometric identity.
$$
\frac{1+\cos(2A)}{\sin(2A)}=\cot A
$$
My work thus far is
$$
\frac{1+\cos^2A-\sin^2A}{2\sin A\cos A}
$$
I know $1-\sin^2A=\cos^2A$

So I do
$$
\frac{\cos^2A+\cos^2A}{2\sin A\cos A}
$$
I know not what I do next.

Comment: $\cos^2 A+\cos^2 A=2\cos^2 A$.

Comment: $\frac{cos^2A+cos^2A}{2\sin A\cos A}=\frac{2\cos^2A}{2\sin A \cos A}=\cot A$

Comment: There's also a nice way of seeing this. Take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120704/how-to-prove-a-trigonometric-identity/126075#126075) by robjohn.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1+\cos(2A)}{\sin(2A)}
&=\frac{1+\cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)}{2\sin(A)\cos(A)}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{\csc^2(A)+\cot^2(A)-1}{2\,\cot(A)}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{2\,\cot^2(A)}{2\,\cot(A)}\tag{3}\\[4pt]
&=\cot(A)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

1. double angle formulas
2. multiply numerator and denominator by $\csc^2(A)$
3. $\cot^2(A)+1=\csc^2(A)$
4. cancel $2\cot(A)$ in numerator and denominator

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{1+\cos(2A)}{\sin(2A)} = \frac{2\cos^2 A}{2\sin A \cdot \cos A} = \frac{\cos A}{\sin A} = \cot A$$

Comment: I have rolled back to TMM's edit, since it is exceptionally clear and easy to read.

Comment: why is this downvoted

Comment: thanks @mixedmath. should I write the answer if someone already give

Answer (score 3):

Just write $\cos^2 A+\cos^2 A=2\cos^2 A$ (a quantity added to itself is twice the quantity). Then write $2\cos^2 A=2\cos A\cdot\cos A$ and  cancel a $2\cos A$ term in the numerator with the $2\cos A$ term in the denominator.