# When do you add $180$ to the directional angle?

Tags: vectors

When finding the direction angle with the formula $\theta = \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right )$, when do you add $180$ degrees to the answer? Is it whenever the $x$ is negative, when the angle is in the third or fourth quadrant (if this is the case, how would I know the angle is there?), or just in the third quadrant (if this is the case, how would I know the angle is there)? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Did you try drawing a picture (one for each case)? In that picture (that you are going to draw), when is the angle $0$? When is it $180$?

Comment: The issue is that ${y \over x} = {-y \over -x}$ so $\arctan$ does not distinguish quadrants $Q_1, Q_3$ or $Q_2, Q_4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [this table in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), you will see that in the **arctangent** row, the "range of usual principal value" is given as $-90^\circ<y<90^\circ$.

This means that if you give a number to the arctangent function, most calculators respond with an answer between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. This is the *half-plane on the right*, quadrants I and IV, so $x$ is assumed positive.

If $x$ is negative, the answer you want is $180^\circ$ away.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Woods' answer is correct, but let me offer another way to compute $\theta$.

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075),
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(\theta/2)
&=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}\\
&=\frac{\frac yr}{1+\frac xr}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{y}{x+r}
\end{align}
$$
which leads to the formula
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\theta=2\arctan\left(\vcenter{\frac y{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\right)}
$$

which is valid as long as $x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ne0$; that is, $y\ne0$ or $x\gt0$.

---

**Verification**

Since $\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(\theta)
&=\frac{2\frac y{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{1-\left(\frac y{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{2y\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)}{2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\[12pt]
&=\frac yx
\end{align}
$$

Comment: And when `x < 0` what is the correct formula?

Comment: You mean when $y=0$ *and* $x\lt0$? In that case, you can take either $\pi$ or $-\pi$, whichever is your preference. When $x\lt0$, if you take $y\gt0$, but very small, you will get something slightly less than $\pi$; if you take $y\lt0$, but very small, you will get something slightly greater than $-\pi$.

Comment: I meant: if I have a point (-1, 1) the result is 1.230959. And if I have a point(1, 1) the result is the same. I'm doing this C formula `angle = 2 * atanl(sY / ( x + sqrtl( (sX*sX) + (sY*sY) )));`. Am I missing something?

Comment: For $(-1,1)$, I get $2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{-1+\sqrt{2}}\right)=2.35619449$. For $(1,1)$, I get $2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)=0.7853981634$.

Comment: @OlivierPons: It looks as if your `x` should be an `sX`. If I put $0$ in where you have `x`, I get the same thing as you got.