# How do we find out angle from $x$ & $y$ coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

I found the following sentence.

> To find the angle you use the arctangent function like this, angle $=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

But I am curious, is this the only way to know the angle?
In other words, is it possible to find the angle with $\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, $\cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$  or $\tan$.. etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any given point $(x, y)$, the angle say $\theta$ of the line, passing through this point & the origin, with the positive x-direction is given as $$\color{blue}{\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}}$$ While other values are given as
$$\color{blue}{\sin\theta=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$$
$$\color{blue}{\cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$$

Comment: How can you find out whether degree or radian?

Comment: The angle obtained is generally in radian which can be changed in degree by multiplying by $\frac{180^o}{\pi}$

Comment: Can I get a hyperbolic function like arctanh sinh tanh.. from sine or cosine function?

Answer (score 6):

Does the picture below help you visualise this? By 'angle' we mean $\theta$ below in plane polar coordinates. For some point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the plane, we can solve for $\theta$ using trigonometry.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Thanks art pictures. Yes so I asking about can we know the angle from any other tri- functions.

Comment: This answer would be improved my including the actual trig to get theta from x0 and y0 here.

Answer (score 5):

In [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3003263), it is shown that
$$
\theta=2\arctan\left(\vcenter{\frac y{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\right)
$$
This formula works for all $x,y$ except on the negative real axis, where $\theta$ goes from just under $\pi$ on top to just above $-\pi$ underneath.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following three formulas to find an angle.

1)$$f(x,y)=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\mbox{sgn}(x))(1-\mbox{sgn}(y^2))-\frac{\pi}{4}\left(2+\mbox{sgn}(x)\right)\mbox{sgn}(y)$$

$$-\mbox{sgn}(xy)*\mbox{atan}\left(\frac{|x|-|y|}{|x|+|y|}\right)$$

2)$$f(x,y)=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\mbox{sgn}(x))(1-\mbox{sgn}(y^2))-\frac{\pi}{4}(2+\mbox{sgn}(x))\mbox{sgn}(y)$$

$$-\mbox{sgn}(xy)\mbox{asin}\left(\frac{\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|}{\sqrt{2*x^2+2*y^2}}\right)$$

3)$$f(x,y)=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\mbox{sgn}(x))(1-\mbox{sgn}(y^2))-\frac{\pi}{4}(2+\mbox{sgn}(x))\mbox{sgn}(y)$$

$$-\mbox{sgn}(\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|)\mbox{sgn}(xy)\mbox{acos}\left(\frac{\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|}{\sqrt{2*x^2+2*y^2}}\right)$$

Each of the formulas give the angle from $0$ to $2\pi$ for any value of $x$ and $y$.

For $x=y=0$, the result is undefined.

Comment: Could you try to use MathJax to format the formula; as is this is hard to read. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The second term of the first formula must be corrected to be the same

Comment: You can [edit] your post. I'm not quite sure what you want to change.

Comment: The second term of the first formula must be corrected to be the same to the second term  of the second and third formula.

Comment: Then please do that.

Comment: What means sgn() and how can it be expressed in C? I guess it's close to: `double xSign = x >= 0 ? 1.0 : -1.0;` but, if so, then what is the point of `(sgn(y²))` (because `y²` is always positive)? Can we say `(sgn(y²))` will always be equals to `1` (if `y != 0`)?

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers seem academic in nature, which I understand might be the way things are around here. You'll have to excuse me because I am new here.

In an Engineering drawing, measurements are generally relative to something. In my case, I wanted an answer relative to the $Y$ axis. The answers here all seem to assume relative to the $X$ axis.

This formula gives me angle relative to the $Y$ axis where if $Y$ is positive then the angle positive is clockwise and negative is counter clockwise.

If $Y$ is negative then it's relative to the negative $Y$ axis and the rotation is reversed.

$$
{\theta=\arctan\left(\vcenter{\frac x{y}}\right)}
$$

This answer is much more simple and it gives the answer I need so I thought I would point that out for anyone trying to apply these answers to real world problems.