# Prove: $\csc a +\cot a = \cot\frac{a}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove: $$\csc a + \cot a = \cot\frac{a}{2}$$

All I have right now, from trig identities, is 
$$\frac{1}{\sin a} + \frac{1}{\tan a} = \frac{1}{\tan(a/2)}$$
Where do I go from there?

Comment: Hint: $\sin 2t = 2\sin t\cos t$, and $\cos 2t = \cos^2 t - \sin^2 t$

Answer (score 1):

Using Double Angle formulae,

$$\dfrac{1+\cos2B}{\sin2B}=\dfrac{2\cos^2B}{2\sin B\cos B}=\text{?}$$

Or use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: Can you explain how you got 1 + cos2B?

Comment: @Matt, $$\csc2B+\cot2B=\dfrac1{\sin2B}+\dfrac{\cos2B}{\sin2B}=?$$

Comment: He took $a=2B$ and replaced $tan$

Comment: How can you make that substitution? I don't see how @DhanushKrishna

Comment: @Matt: Just replacing $a$ to make the calculations easier. It does not change anything. Finally you must replace it.

Answer (score 1):

We start with the following identities: $\quad\sin(2a) = 2\sin a \cos a\quad$ $\quad\cos(2a) = 1-2\sin^2 a\quad$
We solve these to get the half-angle identities: $\quad \sin(a) = 2\sin \frac a2 \cos \frac a2\quad$$\quad\sin^2 \frac a2 = \frac 12 (1-\cos a)$
We now tackle the problem
$$\frac{1}{\sin a} + \frac{\cos a}{\sin a} = \frac{\cos \frac a2}{\sin \frac a2}$$
multiplying out both sides we get that
$$2\sin^2 \frac a2(\cos a + 1) =2\sin \frac a2\cos \frac{a}{2} \sin a$$
Using the identities above we get that
$$(1-\cos a)(1+\cos a) = \sin^2 a$$
$$\implies 1 - \cos^2 a = \sin^2 a$$
$$\implies 1  = \sin^2 a + \cos^2 a$$
We now have a trivial trigonometric identity, so the equivalence is proved

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075):
$$
\begin{align}
\csc(a)+\cot(a)
&=\frac{1+\cos(a)}{\sin(a)}\\
&=\frac1{\tan(a/2)}\\[6pt]
&=\cot(a/2)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know the most conventional tangent half-angle formula
$$
\tan \frac a 2 = \frac{\sin a}{1+\cos a}
$$
then you can take reciprocals of both sides, getting
$$
\frac 1 {\tan \frac a 2} = \frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a} = \frac 1 {\sin a} + \frac{\cos a}{\sin a} = \csc a + \cot a.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\csc a+\cot a=\cot\frac{a}2$

L.H.S.

$\implies\large \frac{1}{\sin a}+\frac{\cos a}{\sin a} \\
\implies \large\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}\\
\implies \large\frac{1+2\cos^2\frac{a}{2}-1}{\sin a}\\
\implies \large\frac{2\cos^2\frac{a}{2}}{2\sin\frac{a}2\cos\frac{a}{2}}\\
\implies \cot \frac{a}{2}=\text{R.H.S}$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution,

$${1\over \sin(a)}= {1\over \tan(a/2)}-{{1-\tan^2(a/2)}\over {2\tan(a/2)}}$$

$${1\over \sin(a)}={1+\tan^2(a/2) \over 2\tan(a/2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Employing Weierstrass half angle relations:

$$\csc a+\cot a=\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}=(1+t^2)/2t +(1-t^2)/2t  = 1/t = \cot a/2 .$$