# Solving $\tan x = \dfrac{\sin 10^\circ + \sin 40^\circ}{ \cos 10^\circ + \cos 40^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $x$ satisfies the equation 
>   $$\tan x = \dfrac{\sin 10^\circ + \sin 40^\circ}{ \cos 10^\circ + \cos 40^\circ}$$
>   and $x$ is between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, then $x$ is equal to what?

Is there an identity I can use here?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, there is a directly relevant identity. It’s a half-angle formula for one of the trig functions.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this in the numerator:

$$\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin \frac{a+b}2 \;\cos \frac{a-b}2$$

And this in the denominator:

$$\cos a + \cos b = 2 \cos \frac{a+b}2\;\cos\frac{a-b}2$$

Divide the numerator by the denominator after applying these sum-product relations, cancel out common factors, and see what you get.

Comment: Just enough hints to stimulate curiosity! +1.

Comment: (+1) The identity that ensues is one of my favorites. It also shows that $\tan\left(\frac a2\right)=\frac{\sin(a)}{1+\cos(a)}$

Answer (score 1):

## Proof Without Words

[image]

$$
\large\color{#8060A0}{\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)}{\cos(a)+\cos(b)}=\tan\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)}
$$

Comment: related to [this proof without words](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075).