# Why does $\log(\tan(x/2))=-\ln|\csc(x)+\cot(x)|$

Tags: trigonometry

Background: This "identity" (if it is one) is motivated by Harris Mathematics for Physical Science question 2.5.4 asking to produce the series for 1/sin(x).

The integral of $\csc(x)$ is $-\ln|\csc(x)+\cot(x)|$, I have never seen it given as $\log(\tan(x/2)$. What identity converts one into the other?

```
series = Integrate[Series[Csc[x], {x, Pi/2, 10}], x]
series2 = Series[Log[Tan[x/2]], {x, Pi/2, 12}]
```

[image]

If you plot them with wolfram alpha you might be confused because the imaginary graph displays different branches of the log function for the two, but they are the same. 
[image]
What likely simple identity am I forgetting or not understanding? Putting the $-\ln|\csc(x)+\cot(x)|$ over a common denominator I think I get $-\ln\mid\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\mid$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\tan\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}=\frac1{\csc(x)+\cot(x)}
$$
The first identity is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075).