# Show that $(z+1)^8-z^8=0$ has roots $z=-\frac12$, $z=-\frac12(1\pm i\cot(k\pi/8))$; and follow-up questions

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots

- (a) Show that the equation $(z+1)^8-z^8=0$ has roots $z=-\frac12$, $-\frac12\left(1\pm i\cot\frac{k\pi}{8}\right)$, where $k=1,2,3$.
- (b) Hence show that
  $$(z+1)^8-z^8=\tfrac18(2z+1)(2z^2+2z+1)\left(4z^2+4z+\csc^2\tfrac{\pi}{8}\right)\left(4z^2+4z+\csc^2\tfrac{3\pi}{8}\right)$$
- (c) By making a suitable substitution into this identity, deduce that
  $$\cos^{16}\theta - \sin^{16}\theta = \tfrac1{16}\cos 2\theta(\cos^22\theta+1)\left(\cos^22\theta+\cot^2\tfrac{\pi}{8}\right)\left(\cos^22\theta+\cot^2\tfrac{3\pi}{8}\right) $$

[original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha3S4.png)

> How do you reformat the polynomial to reach the answer required?

I have tried to turn the LHS into $[(z+1)/z]^8 = 0$ and solve the roots of unity, but I keep getting $\operatorname{cis}(2k\pi/8)$ instead of $k\pi/8$ which is required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you wrote "$[(z+1)/z]^8=0$", did you mean "$[(z+1)/z]^8-1=0$"?

Answer (score 1):

By your method

$$(z+1)^8-z^8=0 \iff \left(1+\frac1z\right)^8=1$$

then let

$$w=1+\frac1z$$

and solve

$$w^8=1 \implies w=e^{\frac{2i\pi k}8}\quad k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$$

but only $7$ solutions are valid since $k=0$ is not acceptable, indeed the original equation is of degree $7$.

The solutions are given by

$$z=\frac1{e^{\frac{2i\pi k}8}-1}=\frac{e^{\frac{-i\pi k}8}}{e^{\frac{i\pi k}8}-e^{\frac{-i\pi k}8}}=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi k}8\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}8\right)}{2i\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}8\right)}=-\frac12-\frac i2\cot \left(\frac{\pi k}8\right)$$

Comment: You forgot a factor of $i$ in the denominator when you switched from exponentials to trig functions.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Opsssss...thanks I fix

Comment: I believe the coefficient of cot should be $-\frac i2$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes of course! I lost the i. Thanks

Comment: Can someone indicate what substitution would be used for part (c).  Thanks

Comment: @Stephan It seems $z=-\sin^2 \theta$ and then using trigonometric identities.

Comment: Cheers.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: Works beautifully!  Thanks.

Comment: @Stephan You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

$$
(1+z)^8=z^8\tag1
$$
$(1)$ implies that
$$
1+z=e^{\pi ik/4}z\tag2
$$
That is
$$
\begin{align}
z
&=\frac1{e^{\pi ik/4}-1}\\
&=\frac1{\cos(\pi k/4)-1+i\sin(\pi k/4)}\\
&=\frac{\cos(\pi k/4)-1-i\sin(\pi k/4)}{(\cos(\pi k/4)-1)^2+\sin^2(\pi k/4)}\\
&=\frac{\cos(\pi k/4)-1-i\sin(\pi k/4)}{2-2\cos(\pi k/4)}\\
&=\frac{-\sin^2(\pi k/4)-i\sin(\pi k/4)(1+\cos(\pi k/4)}{2\sin^2(\pi k/4))}\\
&=-\frac12-\frac i2\cot(\pi k/8)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
where we have used [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075)
$$
\tan(x/2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\tag4
$$