# How to find the angle of a rotation 2 by 2 matrix?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

A 2 by 2 matrix is given with irrational elements and we can derive that the top left element is equal to $\cos(θ)$, and the bottom left element is equal to $\sin(θ)$.

How could we find the value of $θ$ and therefore the angle that the rotation does. I think by using the signs of the trigonometric functions in each quadrant.

Comment: $\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$

Comment: Isn't it just a case of using [inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)? Although, as you say, you also have to consider the signs of both values to check which quadrant it's in.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What's the advantage of using an inverse $\tan$ as opposed to an inverse $\sin$ or $\cos$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126075), a nice formula for getting $\theta$ from $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ that takes care of quadrants is
$$
\theta=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}\right)\tag1
$$
The only ambiguity might be when $\cos(\theta)=-1$, where we get $2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac00\right)$. In this case, $\theta$ could be  $\pm\pi$.